# Japanese quotation marks do not display as full-width

Tags: punctuation, xecjk, white-space, japanese

When I use Japanese quotation marks at the start of a line, the whitespace at the beginning of the character seems to get cut off, moving the quotation mark half a space forward. This puts the text out of alignment when it should look like its aligned to a grid.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item
「あああああああああああああ」

　あああああああああああああ。

「あああああああああああああ」

　あああああああああああああ。
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Is there any way to force the quotation marks to display properly at their full-width without trimming the whitespace?

Answer (score 2):

I do not know why this is, except that it seems like it's the kind of thing that is intended so as not to leave a space at the beginning of a line. But you can work around it by inserting a `\strut` before the opening bracket:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item \strut「あああああああああああああ」

    　あああああああああああああ。

    \strut「あああああああああああああ」

    　あああああああああああああ。
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

An alternative is to insert a half width space in your second lines:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\newlength{\cjktextsize}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\cjkhalfspace}{%
  \setlength{\cjktextsize}{\f@size pt}%
  \hspace*{0.5\cjktextsize}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item「あああああああああああああ」

   \cjkhalfspace あああああああああああああ。

   「あああああああああああああ」

   \cjkhalfspace あああああああああああああ。
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]